# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, cloudinary

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxUnG.png)I have added a page to complete his profile after creating an account indicating only the e-mail address and password, so we find ourselves on the page that completes his profile, add photos to His account ... everything works well if I fill the fields correctly and I upload photos, I can validate and my profile is updated, the problem comes when I forget to fill a mandatory field (example: address or first_name. ..) and that I had already upload a photos, so I have a render that tells me that I forgot fields and when I complete them and validate, it is that cloudinary makes a mistake

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#update
>
> Couldn't find Attachinary::File with 'id'=18

params :

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"TaAxCldr0Hi2r81Oat3i9ERK8TWapiICbCeyf7J3oR6UDVSnqEoNsOjcJ6ms9Ms8MOPlYUc7mKL9A4sp+Hg4IQ==", "user"=><ActionController::Parameters {"last_name"=>"fezfzgz", "first_name"=>"gzrgrzg", "birthday(1i)"=>"2013", "birthday(2i)"=>"8", "birthday(3i)"=>"22", "gender"=>"homme", "website"=>"zesvzzeze", "phone_number"=>"102030405", "avaibility"=>"false", "description"=>"", "address"=>"zregregreg", "zip_code"=>"13210", "city"=>"france", "photos"=>["[{\"id\":18,\"public_id\":\"j3b5qdc90jj77ygib26f\",\"version\":\"1503409614\",\"format\":\"jpg\",\"resource_type\":\"image\",\"path\":\"v1503409614/j3b5qdc90jj77ygib26f.jpg\"}]"], "videos"=>[""], "voice_attribute"=>"grave", "voices"=>[""]} permitted: false>, "commit"=>"Save", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"18"} permitted: false>
```

current_user :

```
 #<User id: 18, email: "davqcze@freel.fr", created_at: "2017-08-22 13:46:21", updated_at: "2017-08-22 13:46:21", first_name: "gzrgrzg", last_name: "fezfzgz", birthday: nil, website: "zesvzzeze", role: "actor", gender: "homme", phone_number: "102030405", voice_attribute: "grave", description: "", avaibility: false, address: "zregregreg", zip_code: "52458", city: "france">
```

Users controller :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @booking = Booking.new
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user
    if current_user.DA?
      if @user.update(user_params_da)
        redirect_to user_path(current_user)
      else
        render :edit
      end
    else
      if @user.update(user_params)
        redirect_to user_path(current_user)
      else
        render :edit
      end
    end
  end


  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(
        :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :address, :city, :birthday,
        :website, :avaibility, :description, :zip_code, :gender, :voice_attribute,
        voices: [], videos: [], photos: []
      )
  end
  def user_params_da
      params.require(:user).permit(
        :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :address, :city, :birthday,
        :website, :description, :zip_code, :gender
        )
  end
end
```

user model :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise         :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
                 :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many       :bookings
  has_many       :projects

  has_attachments :photos, maximum: 10 #limiting upload to 10 units
  has_attachments :videos, maximum: 10 #limiting upload to 10 units
  has_attachments :voices, maximum: 10 #limiting upload to 10 units


  validates :first_name, presence: :true, on: :update, unless: :devise?
  validates :last_name, presence: :true, on: :update, unless: :devise?
  validates :zip_code, presence: :true, on: :update, unless: :devise?
  validates :address, presence: :true, on: :update, unless: :devise?
  validates :city, presence: :true, on: :update, unless: :devise?
  validates :phone_number, presence: :true, on: :update, unless: :devise?
  validates :gender, presence: :true, on: :update, unless: :devise?
  validates :birthday, presence: :true, on: :update, unless: :devise?
   with_options if: :actor? do |actor|
    actor.validates_inclusion_of :avaibility, :in => [true, false], on: :update
    actor.validates :voice_attribute, presence: :true, on: :update
    actor.validates :voice_attribute, presence: :true, on: :update, unless: :devise?
  end

  enum voice_attribute: [:grave, :moyen, :aigu]
  enum gender: [:femme, :homme]
  enum role: [:DA, :actor]


  private

  def devise?
    email_changed? || encrypted_password_changed?
  end
end
```

[https://preview.ibb.co/fxVW45/Capture_du_2017_08_22_23_52_21.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOaoB.png)

Comment: can you add picture of error?

Comment: Seems that the problem is in the `Attachinary` config no? Can you share the User model validations or the full stack trace?

Comment: i just add the user model and a picture of error ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found a solution adding in the New View

```
<%= f.input :photo_cache, as: :hidden %>
```

in the model

`has_attachment :photo_cache`

and also putting :photo_cache in the strong params in my controller